# Electron AppDirectory module problems

Tags: node.js, electron

I used AppDirectory module to store the setting of my app in OS X and everything works.
So logging this:

```
var AppDirectory = require('appdirectory');
var dirs = new AppDirectory('myAppName');
var fs = require("fs");
console.log("user data:"+dirs.userData());
console.log("user config:"+dirs.userConfig());
console.log("user cache:"+dirs.userCache() );
console.log("user logs:"+dirs.userLogs() );
```

in MAC (OSX) I get this:

```
user data:/Users/myUser/Library/Application Support/myAppName
user config:/Users/myUser/Library/Application Support/myAppName
user cache:/Users/myUser/Library/Caches/myAppName
user logs:/Users/myUser/Library/Logs/myAppName
```

So I'm storing the config file in dirs.userData()

On Windows I have a strenge problem , the output in Windows is:

```
user data:C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\ myAppName\myAppName
user config:C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\ myAppName\myAppName
user cache:C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\ myAppName\myAppName\Cache
user logs:C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\ myAppName\ myAppName\Logs
```

As you can see the name of the app is repeated twice in the URI, but this is not the only problem if I go in the corresponding folder: C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\
there is no myAppName directory and also going in C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Roaming\ I see no folders with the name of my app...

Please note I'm using Windows 7 (in a virtual machine with parallels) and Electron 0.36.11

Can you please help me so solve this?
Thanks you in advance.